# How can i customize the design of this canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, canvas

I started to work on an animation and im getting pretty close to what it should look like, but as you can see on from my snippet the "lines" are pointy and does not look like the design i have posted below. Could anyone check the code provided and the external code in the snippet and help me figure out what is controlling the design of the "lines" i have gone through the entire code multiple times without finding an answer. All help is appreciated thank you.

This is what i wish my "lines" in the animation should look like.

[image: Background animation]

```js
// Settings
var particleCount = 35,
flareCount = 0,
motion = 0.05,
tilt = 0,
particleSizeBase = 1,
particleSizeMultiplier = 0.5,
flareSizeBase = 100,
flareSizeMultiplier = 100,
glareAngle = -60,
glareOpacityMultiplier = 0.4,
renderParticles = true,
renderParticleGlare = true,
renderFlares = false,
renderLinks = false,
renderMesh = false,
flicker = false,
flickerSmoothing = 15, // higher = smoother flicker
blurSize = 0,
orbitTilt = true,
randomMotion = true,
noiseLength = 1000,
noiseStrength = 3;

document.querySelectorAll('.stars').forEach(canvas => {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  color = canvas.dataset['color'],
  mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 },
  m = {},
  r = 0,
  c = 1000, // multiplier for delaunay points, since floats too small can mess up the algorithm
  n = 0,
  nAngle = (Math.PI * 2) / noiseLength,
  nRad = 100,
  nScale = 1,
  nPos = {x: 0, y: 0},
  points = [],
  vertices = [],
  triangles = [],
  links = [],
  particles = [],
  flares = [];

  function init() {
    var i, j, k;

    // requestAnimFrame polyfill
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function( callback ){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();


    // Size canvas
    resize();

    mouse.x = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
    mouse.y = canvas.clientHeight / 2;

    // Create particle positions
    for (i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
      var p = new Particle();
      particles.push(p);
      points.push([p.x*c, p.y*c]);
    }


    vertices = Delaunay.triangulate(points);


    var tri = [];
    for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      if (tri.length == 2) {
        triangles.push(tri);
        tri = [];
      }
      tri.push(vertices[i]);
    }


    // Tell all the particles who their neighbors are
    for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      // Loop through all tirangles
      for (j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++) {
        // Check if this particle's index is in this triangle
        k = triangles[j].indexOf(i);
        // If it is, add its neighbors to the particles contacts list
        if (k !== -1) {
          triangles[j].forEach(function(value, index, array) {
            if (value !== i && particles[i].neighbors.indexOf(value) == -1) {
              particles[i].neighbors.push(value);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }

    var fps = 60;
    var now;
    var then = Date.now();
    var interval = 1000/fps;
    var delta;
    // Animation loop
    (function animloop(){
      requestAnimFrame(animloop);
      now = Date.now();
      delta = now - then;
      if (delta > interval) {


        then = now - (delta % interval);

        resize();
        render();
      }

    })();
  }

  function render() {
    if (randomMotion) {
      n++;
      if (n >= noiseLength) {
        n = 0;
      }

      nPos = noisePoint(n);

    }



    if (renderParticles) {
      // Render particles
      for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
        particles[i].render();
      }
    }


  }

  function resize() {

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
    canvas.height = canvas.width * (canvas.clientHeight / canvas.clientWidth);

  }



  // Particle class
  var Particle = function() {
    this.x = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
    this.y = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
    this.z = random(0,4);
    this.color = color;
    this.opacity = random(0.1,1,true);
    this.flicker = 0;
    this.neighbors = []; // placeholder for neighbors
  };
  Particle.prototype.render = function() {
    var pos = position(this.x, this.y, this.z),
    r = ((this.z * particleSizeMultiplier) + particleSizeBase) * (sizeRatio() / 1000),
    o = this.opacity;



    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.globalAlpha = o;
    context.beginPath();

    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    if (renderParticleGlare) {
      context.globalAlpha = o * glareOpacityMultiplier;

      context.ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, r * 100, r, (glareAngle - ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength * motion)) * (Math.PI / 180), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fill();
      context.closePath();
    }

    context.globalAlpha = 1;
  };

  // Utils

  function noisePoint(i) {
    var a = nAngle * i,
    cosA = Math.cos(a),
    sinA = Math.sin(a),


    rad = nRad;
    return {
      x: rad * cosA,
      y: rad * sinA
    };
  }

  function position(x, y, z) {
    return {
      x: (x * canvas.width) + ((((canvas.width / 2) - mouse.x + ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion),
      y: (y * canvas.height) + ((((canvas.height / 2) - mouse.y + ((nPos.y - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion)
    };
  }

  function sizeRatio() {
    return canvas.width >= canvas.height ? canvas.width : canvas.height;
  }

  function random(min, max, float) {
    return float ?
    Math.random() * (max - min) + min :
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }


  // init
  if (canvas) init();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0%, #000000 100%);
  height: 100%;
}

#stars {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ironwallaby/delaunay/master/delaunay.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.15/minified/require.js"></script>

<canvas id="Stars" class="stars" width="300" height="300" data-color="#fff"></canvas>
```

Comment: In `Particle.prototype.render`, you'll find the lines you see are actually a glare effect for particles, using ellipses → `context.ellipse(...)`. That's where some work needs to be done

Comment: @blex Thank you so much for finding where the design is created. Atleast im working on the right place now. Would you perhaps know anything more about how i would achieve what im looking for? Ive tried changing a lot and see no difference in the design besides the length of the line or direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What are these lines?

In the code, you'll find a `Particle.prototype.render` method. This is used to draw a dot (star), and its glare effect. The glare effect corresponds to the lines you see, and they are made using [**`ellipse`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/ellipse):

```
context.ellipse(pos.x, pos.y, r * 100, r, (glareAngle - ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength * motion)) * (Math.PI / 180), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
```

### How to get this skewed rectangle effect instead?

To get the effect you want, you need to replace this ellipse with a rectangle, using [**`fillRect`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect):

```
context.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, r * noiseStrength, r * 100);
```

But that is not enough. Our rectangles go straight down, they don't follow the glare angle, so we need to skew them. This can be achieved using the [**`setTransform`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) method:

```
context.setTransform(1, 0, (glareAngle/100), 1, 0, 0);
```

That leaves us with this code:

```
Particle.prototype.render = function() {
  /* ... */

  if (renderParticleGlare) {
    context.globalAlpha = o * glareOpacityMultiplier;
    // Set the transformation before drawing the glare
    context.setTransform(1, 0, (glareAngle/100), 1, 0, 0);
    // Draw the glare
    context.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, r * noiseStrength, r * 100);
    context.closePath();
  }

  context.globalAlpha = 1;
};
```

### Demo

```js
// Settings
var particleCount = 35,
flareCount = 0,
motion = 0.05,
tilt = 0,
particleSizeBase = 1,
particleSizeMultiplier = 0.5,
flareSizeBase = 100,
flareSizeMultiplier = 100,
glareAngle = -60,
glareOpacityMultiplier = 0.4,
renderParticles = true,
renderParticleGlare = true,
renderFlares = false,
renderLinks = false,
renderMesh = false,
flicker = false,
flickerSmoothing = 15, // higher = smoother flicker
blurSize = 0,
orbitTilt = true,
randomMotion = true,
noiseLength = 1000,
noiseStrength = 8;

document.querySelectorAll('.stars').forEach(canvas => {
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  color = canvas.dataset['color'],
  mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 },
  m = {},
  r = 0,
  c = 1000, // multiplier for delaunay points, since floats too small can mess up the algorithm
  n = 0,
  nAngle = (Math.PI * 2) / noiseLength,
  nRad = 100,
  nScale = 1,
  nPos = {x: 0, y: 0},
  points = [],
  vertices = [],
  triangles = [],
  links = [],
  particles = [],
  flares = [];

  function init() {
    var i, j, k;

    // requestAnimFrame polyfill
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function( callback ){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();


    // Size canvas
    resize();

    mouse.x = canvas.clientWidth / 2;
    mouse.y = canvas.clientHeight / 2;

    // Create particle positions
    for (i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
      var p = new Particle();
      particles.push(p);
      points.push([p.x*c, p.y*c]);
    }


    vertices = Delaunay.triangulate(points);


    var tri = [];
    for (i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
      if (tri.length == 2) {
        triangles.push(tri);
        tri = [];
      }
      tri.push(vertices[i]);
    }


    // Tell all the particles who their neighbors are
    for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      // Loop through all tirangles
      for (j = 0; j < triangles.length; j++) {
        // Check if this particle's index is in this triangle
        k = triangles[j].indexOf(i);
        // If it is, add its neighbors to the particles contacts list
        if (k !== -1) {
          triangles[j].forEach(function(value, index, array) {
            if (value !== i && particles[i].neighbors.indexOf(value) == -1) {
              particles[i].neighbors.push(value);
            }
          });
        }
      }
    }

    var fps = 60;
    var now;
    var then = Date.now();
    var interval = 1000/fps;
    var delta;
    // Animation loop
    (function animloop(){
      requestAnimFrame(animloop);
      now = Date.now();
      delta = now - then;
      if (delta > interval) {


        then = now - (delta % interval);

        resize();
        render();
      }

    })();
  }

  function render() {
    if (randomMotion) {
      n++;
      if (n >= noiseLength) {
        n = 0;
      }

      nPos = noisePoint(n);

    }



    if (renderParticles) {
      // Render particles
      for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
        particles[i].render();
      }
    }


  }

  function resize() {

    canvas.width = window.innerWidth * (window.devicePixelRatio || 1);
    canvas.height = canvas.width * (canvas.clientHeight / canvas.clientWidth);

  }



  // Particle class
  var Particle = function() {
    this.x = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
    this.y = random(-0.1, 1.1, true);
    this.z = random(0,4);
    this.color = color;
    this.opacity = random(0.1,1,true);
    this.flicker = 0;
    this.neighbors = []; // placeholder for neighbors
  };
  Particle.prototype.render = function() {
    var pos = position(this.x, this.y, this.z),
    r = ((this.z * particleSizeMultiplier) + particleSizeBase) * (sizeRatio() / 1000),
    o = this.opacity;



    context.fillStyle = this.color;
    context.globalAlpha = o;
    context.beginPath();

    context.fill();
    context.closePath();

    if (renderParticleGlare) {
      context.globalAlpha = o * glareOpacityMultiplier;
      // Set the transformation before drawing the glare
      context.setTransform(1, 0, (glareAngle/100), 1, 0, 0);
      // Draw the glare
      context.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, r * noiseStrength, r * 100);
      context.closePath();
    }

    context.globalAlpha = 1;
  };

  // Utils

  function noisePoint(i) {
    var a = nAngle * i,
    cosA = Math.cos(a),
    sinA = Math.sin(a),


    rad = nRad;
    return {
      x: rad * cosA,
      y: rad * sinA
    };
  }

  function position(x, y, z) {
    return {
      x: (x * canvas.width) + ((((canvas.width / 2) - mouse.x + ((nPos.x - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion),
      y: (y * canvas.height) + ((((canvas.height / 2) - mouse.y + ((nPos.y - 0.5) * noiseStrength)) * z) * motion)
    };
  }

  function sizeRatio() {
    return canvas.width >= canvas.height ? canvas.width : canvas.height;
  }

  function random(min, max, float) {
    return float ?
    Math.random() * (max - min) + min :
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }


  // init
  if (canvas) init();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00) 0%, #000000 100%);
  height: 100%;
}

#stars {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/ironwallaby/delaunay/master/delaunay.js"></script>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.15/minified/require.js"></script>

<canvas id="Stars" class="stars" width="300" height="300" data-color="#fff"></canvas>
```